# How to login to chrome with selenium they logout when I use it

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm learning Scraping with python + selenium.

### Wish

I want to login google and chrome when I use selenium.
and popele say It's detecting a automation mode for bot detection. So you should hide you are using selenium.

That's why I wrote this code.

Here is my code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from requests.exceptions import Timeout
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--window-size=1280,800')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 3')
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36')
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome("selenium/chromedriver", options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.co.jp/')
time.sleep(1000)
```

My user profile is not working. When using selenium, It doesn't show me as signed in.

`chrome://version`

[image]

### Tried answering code

I got this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: excludeSwitches
```

Changed My code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from requests.exceptions import Timeout
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--window-size=1280,800')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/Users/wakasugiwataru/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 3')
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1557")
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36')
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome("selenium/chromedriver", options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.co.jp/')
time.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: Type chrome://version and add that screen shot

Comment: I don't see any difference between the screenshots. How can you claim Google is detecting a automation mode for bot detection?

Comment: @PDHide My ver is 87.0.4280.67（Official Build） （x86_64)

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm not try to avoid bot detecting.

Comment: Not version just type that in address bar and it shows your profile

Comment: @PDHide  I added screenshots.

Comment: @wataru its not working because you copied only the profile directory copy the entire user data directory as session are stored in this directory , else connect to a already opened chrome . I have added the answer

Comment: The new error is the exclude switch error remove all your add arguments and use the code I gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are two ways:**

**use the userdata folder that you used with normal browser, when you copy the profile to a new folder copy the entire user data folder not only the profile. Your login informations will be in the user data not in profile**

```
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome')
options.add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 3')
```

you don't need to provide -- with add_argument above code will use the exiting profile 3

***But this will not allow to login to google in your case because you copied only the profile not the user data folder***

**Another way to connect is to connect to a already logged in browser session:**

follow below steps :

1. open chrome.exe as :

Connecting to an existing chrome browser from selenium:
close all chrome browsers and then, start the Chrome browser in debug mode by opening cmd and running chrome.exe with — remote-debugging-port argument

```
"<path>\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=1557
```

Now open any other browser and navigate to localhost:1557 to check that the browser was indeed opened with that port
Now in selenium code use chrome experimental option to connect to this chrome option

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1557");
browser=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: `"<path>\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=1559` and `options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1557");` is that same meaning of both code? `"<path>\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=1559` code is for using in terminal??

Comment: I tried your answer but It didn't work. I got error. I added changed code and error. please check that something wrong.

Comment: First code is to open chrome with the specified debug portal that is run in terminal , and second code is python code to connect to that already opened browser

Comment: That means First should I open a chrome from terminal like this `open -a '/Applications/Google Chrome.app' --remote-debugging-port=1559` and second try to run a code right??

Comment: I run above your code but nothing just happen. it was like a server listening.

Comment: /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222&

Comment: Change it to 1559 , after opening try opening localhost:1559 in browser and see you can view something

Comment: Now login to google and then run the code , now what ever you do in selenium  will happen  in the browser which you just logged in. Also login to google

Comment: Incod winstead 1559 I had mentioned 1557 , I have changed everything to 1557

Answer (score 0):

When you access *Google Chrome Browser* for the first time after installation, initially *Chrome* offers you a *Guest Login* and *Chrome* would ask you to *Sign in with your *Google Account* credentials to access your bookmarks, history, passwords, and other settings* synced up within your *Google Account*.

[image: ChromeGuest]

At this stage you are accessing *Google Chrome Browser* as a **guest** user without any access to bookmarks, history, passwords, and other settings. To access your bookmarks, history, passwords, and other settings you have to login with your Google Account credentials. Once you successfully login you will be able to see the logged in icon at the top right hand corner.

[image: ChromeLoggedIn]

Now, each time you would access *Google Chrome Browser*, all your bookmarks, history, passwords, and other settings would be synced up within your *Google Account*. Hence you find yourself logged in.

---

### Accessing Chrome with Selenium

When you spin up a [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* the *Browsing Context* is opened with a ***Guest Login***. Hence you are not shown as **signed in**.

Comment: I didn't know about guest mode thank you so much good infomation.

Comment: @wataru Actually, I tried to answer your initial query within your first version of your question. No doubt you updated your question now without understanding the basic ideas. Good luck :)

Comment: Sorry some one edit my question and I agreed that editing. What do you mean? There is another solution??

Comment: @wataru You agreed to a bad edit to your question and accepted the answer which doesn't address your actual query. So question is what have you gained?

Comment: I can use the browser which logged into chrome with selenium.

Comment: @wataru You seem to be double lucky. Your initial version of your question was, why aren't you logged in using Selenium and in return you got an answer how login through logged in chrome. All the best.

Comment: Yeah you're right I'm so sorry. Your answer is correct first my question.